# Relocating Cake's default layouts folder

Tags: cakephp, path, cakephp-1.2

I'm working on a CakePHP 1.2 app where I don't have control over the /app directory and have relocated my views folder to, say /path/to/mycomponent/views and can render my views by setting my controller's default view path

```
var $viewPath = "mycomponent/views";
```

I have some layouts (including basic.ctp) under /path/to/mycomponent/views/layouts

Is there a way to render my views inside a specific layout?

Calling this from my controller gives me a page not found error:

```
function index()
    {
        $this->autoLayout = true;
        $this->pageTitle = 'Browse items';
        $this->render("browse", "basic");
        // also tried: $this->render("browse", "/path/to/mycomponent/views/layouts/basic.ctp");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work by adding a path to the viewPaths array of the app configuration. This code goes in you controller constructor or in the override beforeFilter metod:

```
$config = Configure::getInstance();
$config->viewPaths[] = " /path/to/mycomponent/views/";
```

Now I can just specify the following:

```
$this->layout = 'basic';
```

And my controller's views render in the `basic.ctp` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just for any further reference.
I believe in cakePhp 2.x it's to be done this way.

> public function beforeRender() {
>           parent::beforeRender();
>           $this->layout = 'mylayout';
>       }

which would go to the path: */app/View/Layouts/mylayout.ctp*

**Note:**

If you want to modify the view paths for some controller, add before the controller class declaration:

> App::build(array('View' => '/Folder/'));
>
> class ExampleController extends AppController{...}

which will set the path for all rendered view for *Example* controller to */app/Views/Folder/*

so the full example would be:

> App::build(array('View' => '/Folder/'));
>
> class ExampleController extends AppController{
>
> ```
> public function beforeRender() {
>     parent::beforeRender();        
>     $this->layout = 'mylayout';
> }  
>
>
> public function index() {
>     $this->render('Home');
>     //This will load view: "/app/Views/Folder/Home.ctp"
>     //From layout: "/app/Views/Layouts/mylayout.ctp"
> }
> ```
>
> }